# AWS S3 put object (video) with pre-signed URL, Not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am uploading a video on S3 bucket via PHP S3 API with pre-signed URL.
The mp4 video is uploaded successfully to S3, but it's not streaming 
and not giving any kind of error.

Here are the details.

My PHP file to create pre-singed url for S3 putObject method.

```
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'ap-south-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'XXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXX'
    ]
]);

/*echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);die;*/

if(!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] || $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']==''){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'false','message'=>'file path is required!'));die;
}else{
    $SourceFile =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $key=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
}

try {
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('putObject', [
    'Bucket'     => 's3-signed-test',
        'Key'        => $key,
        'SourceFile' => $SourceFile,
        'debug' => false,
        'ACL' => 'public-read-write',
        'ContentType' => 'video/mp4',
        'CacheControl'=>'no-cache',
        'ContentLength'=>$size

]);


$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+120 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();


} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";die;
}

echo json_encode(array('status'=>'true','signedUrl'=>$presignedUrl));die;
```

This code is working fine and uploading video mp4 on s3 bucket.

But after upload when I am going to access that video, it's not working 
I have tried also with getObject pre-singed url but it's not working.

Here are the S3  object URLs-

(1) getObject pre-singed URL

https://s3-signed-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/file.mp4?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIVUO7AT4W4MCPDIA%2F20180402%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180402T112848Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7200&X-Amz-Signature=d6b877f9bba5dd2221381f10017c8659fe42342d81f7af940d8693478679a8fc

(2) S3 Direct object URL-

https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/s3-signed-test/file.mp4

My  **Problem** is I am unable to access video which I have uploaded with pre-singed URL on the s3 bucket, bucket permission is public, and accessible for all origins.

Please let me know, someone who have solution for this.

Comment: You need to create an Cloudfront Distribution to stream data. Link: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But I have already check with CloudFront the video stream is also not working with this.
(1) The video which is uploaded by singed URL API is unable to stream check this link- http://dj2mwlqtms3kq.cloudfront.net/file.mp4
(2) The video which is uploaded by S3 console are streaming fine
check this link -http://dj2mwlqtms3kq.cloudfront.net/file1.mp4
====
all the permission and metadata are same for both videos, I am unable to understand the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using Cloudfront with OAI ? Also, have you tried uploading using PHP but without presign ?

Comment: Yes, its working without pre-sign, and the bucket is public so don't need to setup OAI.